# How do i use a web browser to FTP with a user/pass where the pass has a @ in it?

Tags: ftp, uri

How do i use a web browser to FTP with a user/pass where the pass has a @ in it?

Example:

ftp://user:p@ssword@192.168.1.1

the above will not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe `ftp://user:p%40ssword@192.168.1.1`?

Comment: I thought this as well, I get a 530 when i try this method.

Comment: @Justin: If that password is correct, maybe the ftp server just can't handle a password encoded like that.

Comment: The above answer should work, i've used similar for usernames that contain a @ sign.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to encode the `@`. See [this page](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/HTML3.2/3.5.html#urlenc) for a reference:

> This encoding (which is defined by URL specifications, not HTML specifications) consists of using the percent sign followed by two hexadecimal digits, presenting the code position.

The at-sign is at code position 40 (hex).

Comment: +1. See also ftp://ftp.funet.fi/pub/doc/rfc/rfc1738.txt (linked from there) p.2